# Changing css on scrolling Angular Style

Tags: angularjs

I want to change CSS elements while a user scrolls the angular way.

here's the code working the JQuery way

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20 && $(window).scrollTop() < 600) {
        $('header, h1, a, div, span, ul, li, nav').css('height','-=10px');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 80) {
        $('header, h1, a, div, span, ul, li, nav').css('height','100px');
    }
```

I tried doing the Angular way with the following code, but the $scope.scroll seemed to be unable to properly pickup the scroll data.

```
forestboneApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $document) {
    $scope.scroll = $($document).scroll();
    $scope.$watch('scroll', function (newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind class toggle to window scroll event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Remember, in Angular, DOM access should happen from within directives. Here's a simple directive that sets a variable based on the `scrollTop` of the window.

```
app.directive('scrollPosition', function($window) {
  return {
    scope: {
      scroll: '=scrollPosition'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var windowEl = angular.element($window);
      var handler = function() {
        scope.scroll = windowEl.scrollTop();
      }
      windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
      handler();
    }
  };
});
```

It's not apparent to me exactly what end result you're looking for, so here's a simple demo app that sets the height of an element to `1px` if the window is scrolled down more than 50 pixels: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Z4VqP/

Comment: Good answer, directives are the way to go here.

Comment: thanks you guys. I'm still getting used to choosing when to write directives over when to try to work with it from scope directly.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is, if you can calculate and change data directly, do it in the controller--but if you need to query, manipulate, or otherwise access the DOM, you probably should use a directive.

Comment: I would improve by adding :
````scope[attrs.scrollPosition] = 0;````
right after windowEl declaration

Comment: Is it possible instead of defaulting `$scope.scroll` to 0, to get the scrolled amount? I'm using this to stick my navbar to the top at a certain amount, and if I scroll down, and refresh (and my browser keeps my place) the navbar doesn't become sticky until I scroll

Comment: @TomHart I've rewritten this directive using AngularJS 1.2.8 to better support writing to the scope (using an isolate scope, now that we have true isolate scopes), as well as setting the initial value as soon as the link function fires.

Comment: @BrandonTilley Your fiddle is a gem, thank you. I've learned so much from it I'd give you a hug. Three little fiddle questions:<br/>
 1. js, line 13: Why are you using 'scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler)' as handler fn? Why can't it simply be 'handler' instead (tried, doesn't work, but why?)?<br/>
 2. js, line 14: Why are you calling the handler fn here? I commented it out and all worked just fine.<br/>
 3. Would the line 11 js assign the value of windowEl.scrollTop() to the $scope.scroll outside the directive if I remover the isolate scope?

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski No problem! (1) You have to `$apply` scope changes that happen asynchronously outside of Angular's own functions so the dirty tracking system picks up the change. (2) In case the user has already scrolled down when the directive is linked; see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/V7GZ2/ (3) Yes, it would, but then the directive is less reusable, because it only works with scope variables named `scroll`.

Comment: ic, so when you are saying 'asynchronously', you mean that whenever I attach handlers to events with element.on()/.off() fn I have to resort to $apply? And what does the .bind() fn do in this context?

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski Yes, that's correct--if Angular isn't already in a digest cycle, you'll have to kick one off for changes to scopes to be detected in the view. `bind` is just the regular `Function.prototype.bind`; I'm just creating a function that will call `scope.$apply` with `$scope` set to the `this` context and `handler` as the first argument to the function. You could also have said `function() { scope.$apply(handler); }`

Comment: Thank you. Now, why would you prefer: `A. scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler)` over `B. function(){scope.$apply(handler);}`? Also, why do you have to bind the scope as `this` to the handler fn? After all `js, line 11` accesses the `$scope` from the `scope` parameter of linking fn. Could it be because again, when you are passing the handler fn to `element.on()`, you are outside of angular and the handler fn can no longer access the scope parameter? On the other hand you are not required to bind `this` to anything in `B.`. So are you, or are you not outside angular when using `element.on()`?

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski (1) Personal preference. (2) It's binding `scope` as `this` in the `$apply` function, not the `handler` function. You have to pass *something* to the first argument of `bind`, and `scope.$apply`'s internal implementation might use `this`, so we pass `scope` to make sure it remains the same--just as if we'd have called `scope.$apply` directly. (3) Yes, when doing manual event binding and using most third-party jQuery plugins, you'll be outside the digest cycle. This comment thread is getting lengthy; feel free to [email me](http://brandontilley.com/contact.html) with any ?s.

Comment: Lenghty indeed, I got this message too. Any how, so there is more to it than just personal preference. Indeed now the A. option seems safer to me too. Your patience with me is highly appreciated :). Cheers.

Comment: For the life of me I can't get this to work. I have the directive copied exactly, my controller is the same and I have this is an html file:              </head>

<body > 
    <div id="header" ng-class="{shadow: scroll > 0}" >
     <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="logoText"></div>
</div>
<div id="content" scroll-position="scroll">                                this div scrolls!

Comment: I think you should wrap the $apply function call into a $timeout callback, to prevent from invocation of $apply inside possible $digest call. 
this works: `windowEl.on('scroll', function(){
       $timeout(function(){
        scope.$apply(handler);
       },0);
      });`