# Angular bind scroll with $scope to be used in ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want banner to hide when user scroll downs.
I took reference from [Bind class toggle to window scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/angularjs-bind-scroll-toggle-class)

I wanted to update a property in scope which I can use later to hide a banner.

Here is the code I have written:
Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/8gYV4/

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('ttlscrollhide', ['$window', function($window){
  return {
    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs) {
      var height = iElm[0].offsetHeight;
      angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        console.log(this.pageYOffset);
        if (this.pageYOffset >= height) {
          $scope.banner.hide = false;
        }
      })
    }
  };
}]).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.banner = {};
  $scope.banner.src = "http://art.exhibition.touchtalent.com/ex-12_2.png";
  $scope.banner.title = "Oho";
  $scope.banner.hide = true;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    if($scope.banner.hide == true) {
      $scope.banner.hide = false;
    } else {
      $scope.banner.hide = true;
    }
  }
}]);
```

---

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ttlscrollhide ng-show="banner.hide">
      <img ng-src="{{banner.src}}">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
</div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

but its not updating the $scope variable. Whereas when I click on toggle button its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('ttlscrollhide', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, iElm, iAttrs) {
            var height = iElm[0].offsetHeight;
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
                console.log('visible : %s < %s %s', this.pageYOffset, height, this.pageYOffset < height);
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.banner.hide = this.pageYOffset < height;
                });
            })
        }
    };
}]).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.banner = {};
    $scope.banner.src = "http://art.exhibition.touchtalent.com/ex-12_2.png";
    $scope.banner.title = "Oho";
    $scope.banner.hide = true;
    $scope.toggle = function () {
        if ($scope.banner.hide == true) {
            $scope.banner.hide = false;
        } else {
            $scope.banner.hide = true;
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div id="test-div" ttlscrollhide ng-show="banner.hide">
            <img ng-src="{{banner.src}}" height="250px">
        </div>
        <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Actually, you have 2 competing problems here :

- First : As you haven't set a height to your image, if you log the height variable, you'll see that it outputs '19', which is a bit small for the image you're using.
- Second : You are manipulating scope variables (banner.hide) from a directive and from an event listener callback, I think this is considered "outside" angular scope, thus you must use `$apply` to notify angular that you're changing the scope from outside.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sephy/G6Lbj/) that seems to work for me. Let me know if it's ok for you.

Hope this helps.