# Why changing AngularJS variable successfully but having no effect?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to make an infinite-scrolling table. I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | limitTo:quantity">
    <td>{{ x.Density }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Pressure }}</td>
<tr>
```

At the end of the table I have a load more button. This works ok:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.quantity = 7;
    $scope.loadMore = function () {   
        $scope.quantity += 7; 
    }
    $scope.names = <?php echo json_encode($records); ?>;
});
</script>
```

While this has no effect:

```
window.onscroll = function () {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()){
        $scope.quantity += 7; 
   }
}
```

The weirdest thing is, if I delete `loadMore()` and use only `window.onscroll` function and keep the button, it doesn't show more result on scroll to bottom but starts to work if I click the button. Yes, even if I have no `loadMore()` function! I am sure the `window.onscroll` is firing on the bottom because `$scope.quantity` keeps increasing.

I am using jQuery mobile if this has anything to do with the problem. I don't think it does because it works fine on button click.

How to make this work only with `window.onscroll` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `onScroll` code isn't running inside the angular digest, which is what detects changes and updates views, notifies watchers, etc ...

You should put the `onscroll` logic inside a directive and do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880862/93321