# Angularjs - unable to properly use directive when window scrolls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I've followed this answer here: [Bind class toggle to window scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event) as I need to bind class using `ngClass` when the window scrolls, and according to the above mentioned answer I should be able to do it like this:

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = true;
                 console.log('Scrolled below header.');
             } else {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = false;
                 console.log('Header is in view.');
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

but when it comes to use this code into my app, it is not firing the directive at all!

Here's my code:
http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/dMNawj?editors=1010

I tried to add a debugger, and I noticed that this directive it's called only when the window loads, but after that it is not called anymore.

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks for any help

Comment: Your code pen doesn't work. i mean angular doesn't bootstrap, it throws a module injection exception.

Comment: I fixed the pen, and it works now. The problem is that on my app no error are thrown but it still doesn't work. Can somebody suggest me something to check that may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I'm actually updating the pen, please give me some time

Comment: Notice that it is a terrible practice to launch digests in unthrottled event handlers, it may bring the browser to its knees.

Comment: @estus what is a better way to do this in your opinion?

Comment: Use throttling function (e.g. underscore/lodash) `var apply = _.throttle(function () { scope.$apply() }, 100, { trailing: true })` and call `apply()` instead of `scope.$apply()`, that's how it is usually done to keep the performance up to par.