# How to get scroll event when kendo-list-view scrolls

Tags: angularjs, kendo-mobile, angular-kendo

I am building a cross platform application using Angular Kendo Mobile.

I have a Kendo list using "kendo-list-view".

```
<div kendo-list-view >
```

I want to get an event when user scrolls this list, in my controller.

I also tried to get the scroll event by using pure angular code, as mentioned in below question.

[Bind class toggle to window scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event)

But in my case nothing happens and code inside the directive is not getting called.

**UPDATE**

I have my HTML with list view as below:

```
<kendo-mobile-view id="myListScreen" k-transition="'slide'" k-title="'My List'" k-layout="'default'" ng-controller="myListCtrl">

    <kendo-mobile-header >
        <kendo-mobile-nav-bar style="background-color: gray">
            <kendo-view-title style="color: white"></kendo-view-title>
            <kendo-mobile-button k-rel="'drawer'" href="#navDrawer" k-align="'left'"><img src="img/menu.png"></kendo-mobile-button>
        </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>

    <div class="myListMainDiv">
        <div kendo-list-view 
             id="myListViewDiv"
             class="myListViewDiv"
             k-template="templates.myListViewItem" 
             k-data-source="myService.listDataSource" 
             ng-show="showListSelected"
             ></div>
   </div>

   <script id="myListViewItem" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div id="{{dataItem.id}}" ng-click="onSelected(dataItem.id)">
           {{dataItem.name}}
        </div>
   </script>

</kendo-mobile-view>
```

I am loading this page in my root page when user selects to navigate to this page using `kendo.mobile.application.navigate("MyList.html");`. And when controller for this page loads I have created list using `new kendo.data.DataSource` and I have attached `new kendo.data.ObservableArray` to my data source.

Comment: Are u using native scrolling in your app?

Comment: @Akis_Tfs I am not sure if I am, I have not set `k-use-native-scrolling="'true'"`

Comment: @Akis_Tfs I have updated my question with my list view sample code.

Comment: @Akis_Tfs In case if kendo-mobile-view has more than one scroll view how can I fond out which list/scroll has generated this scroll event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the scroll event from the `Scroller` of your Kendo Mobile View,
For example if you have a view with `id="myListScreen"`:

```
    var kendoView = $('#myListScreen').data().kendoMobileView;
    var scroller = kendoView.scroller;

    scroller.bind("scroll", function(e) {
        console.log(e.scrollTop);
        console.log(e.scrollLeft);
    });
```

You can find more info about the kendo scroller [here on their documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/scroller#events-scroll)

Comment: Thanks for replay, but when I try this code then I don't get event in my call back method. I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scroller' of undefined` in my logs, so `data().kendoMobileView` is null.

Comment: @A_user hmm you should be able to get the Kendo Mobile View with this way. Can you please show the code where you define your Kendo View?

Comment: @Akis-tfs - I have updated my question with my list view code.

Comment: @Akis-tfs -- Thanks for update, I will try it. But problem is that I have 2-3 scrolling lists in one page so how can I get to know which list user is scrolling. In my code example I have given only one list for example. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @Akis-Tfs I tried this solution and works very well, and I am able to get scroll events now. but what to do if we have more than tow lists inside kenod-mobile-view how we can figure out which list is scrolling. Thanks again for providing help.

Comment: @A_user hmm i will try to recreate a view with 2 lists at some point, for now what i can tell is that the event object has a `sender` property. So try to `console.log(e.sender);` and see what u can find there

Comment: In my case sender.id is null. I have printed `e` and in that I don't see any of the property holding sender name/id.

Comment: How to get event when `kendo-mobile-scroller` content is scrolled I am trying apply same login but it is not working, can you please help.