# AngularJS: why can't I toggle a class binding to the window scroll event?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to toggle a class on an element if/when the page has scrolled.

I have followed [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event) but when I try chaining in a directive, I don't even get to the log statements.

Trying to follow along with the angular docs, I've got my `component.js` file like this. I can get the log statements to show, but the class never gets toggled.

**dashboard.component.js**

```
angular.module('dashboard')
    .component('dashboard', {
    'templateUrl': 'dashboard/dashboard.template.html',
    controller: function dashboardController($scope, $window, $mdSidenav) {
        var primaryAppBar = angular.element(document.querySelector('#primaryAppBar'));

        angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
            if (this.pageYOffset > 0) {
                console.log('add shadow');
                $scope.boolChangeClass = true;
            } else {
                console.log('remove shadow');
                $scope.boolChangeClass = false;
            }
        });
        ...
```

**app-bar.template.html**

```
<md-toolbar id="primaryAppBar" ng-class="{'md-whiteframe-1dp':boolChangeClass}">
...
```

Comment: Is the scope you're modifying in _dashboard.component.js_ the same as in _app-bar.template.html_? I see nothing to indicate that it is.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein It should be painfully obvious how much I have to learn. That was in fact the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll add an answer so you can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope in *dashboard.component.js* is not the same scope as in *app-bar.template.html*. Either have them be under the same controller or provide something to pass the `boolChangeClass` variable.