# If scroll up then $scope value change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have simple div with stuff inside:

```
<div>...</div>
```

and a scope for example:

```
$scope.test = false;
```

Is there  a simply way to change this $scope to true, when i scroll up on div?

Comment: Have you taken a look at? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

```
        angular.element('div').bind('scroll', function () {
            $scope.test = true;
        });
```

may be you can try it out, just bind the event to the div you want and set the $scope.test to true when that event happens