# Styling for CSS class not getting applied when class is added using Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a header that is localized under a div. When you scroll and the header reaches the top of the page it should "stay" there. I am using Angular so I found this solution: [Bind class toggle to window scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event/38772370#38772370) here and I am using it for adding the class `fix-header`. In the inspector I can see that the class gets added but the styling does not apply when it is added. Here is my CSS for making the header fixed:

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .fix-header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
```

The "fix-search" class is added here:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="dummy-container"></div>
      <div class="wrapper" change-class-on-scroll offset="200" scroll-
           class="fix-header">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

The line `change-class-on-scroll offset="200" scroll-class="fix-header"` adds the class `fix-header` to the `wrapper` div.
Here is some working code: https://codepen.io/Martin36/pen/jmbEgJ

So my question is, why doesn't the class properties get applied when the class is added?

Comment: give it a width

Comment: @Ronnie Thank you, now I can see the header when I scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why don't the styles get applied when the class is added?**

Because you are referencing the wrong class, your CSS target should be:

```
.wrapper.fix-header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Note no space between the wrapper class and the fix-header class

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I incorporated the comment given by @Ronnie and the answer from @cnorthfield and made an updated pen: https://codepen.io/Martin36/pen/jmbEgJ, for those of you that are interested. The header now sticks to the top of the screen when the "dummy" div is scrolled past. The following changes were made:

```
/* Since the classes are on the same element there should not be a blank between them */
.wrapper.fix-header{
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
  /* Without the "width" the header disappears */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on cnorthfield's answer:

```
/*Apply style to all elements of both the wrapper class and the fix-header class*/
.wrapper .fix-header
{

}

/*Apply style to all elements which have both the wrapper and fix-header classes*/
.wrapper.fix-header
{

}
```

Notice how the addition/removal of a single space significantly changes the meaning of the selector.