# Page Scroll Event using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I want to bind a page scroll event in my angular directive. I am trying the following code snippet. But it seems the event won't get fired:

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
    console.log('page scrolled');
});
```

I need help, how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you make sure that you've injected $window with your controller? also you can check with this existing [plunker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878761/bind-class-toggle-to-window-scroll-event) solution.

Comment: This seems to work as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/VFOo1Beg7zpL0VCWWQRi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$window`, you may inject `$document` wrapper for the browser's `window.document` (see the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document)) and use

```
$document.bind('scroll', function(event) {
  console.log('page scrolled');
});
```