# AngularJS 'scrollTop' equivalent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to implement something similar to this in an AngularJS directive:

https://github.com/geniuscarrier/scrollToTop/blob/master/jquery.scrollToTop.js

It's fairly straightforward, when you are not at the top of the page it will fade in a button to scroll to the top:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $this.fadeIn();
  } else {
    $this.fadeOut();
  }
});
```

However I'm having a hard time finding how to get the current scroll location in Angular. I'd rather not have to use jQuery just for this single thing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$window.pageYOffset
```

This is property from service $window

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's anything in Angular to get the scroll position.  Just use plain vanilla JS.

You can retrieve the scrollTop property on any element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/cdwgsbq5/

Comment: This results in different behavior in chrome and firefox. Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Inject the $window into your controller and you can get the scroll position on scroll

```
var windowEl = angular.element($window);
var handler = function() {
    console.log(windowEl.scrollTop())
}
windowEl.on('scroll', handler);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Z4VqP/)

Adaptation from another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549216/changing-css-on-scrolling-angular-style)

Comment: I would guess that this is accessing the jqLite ( or jQuery ) method?

Comment: yep with Angular's jqlite !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
angular.element(document).bind('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollTop() > 100) {
        $this.fadeIn();
    } else {
        $this.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like as polyfill
here a [link](https://siongui.github.io/2013/05/12/angularjs-get-element-offset-position/)

```
function offset(elm) {
  try {return elm.offset();} catch(e) {}
  var rawDom = elm[0];
  var _x = 0;
  var _y = 0;
  var body = document.documentElement || document.body;
  var scrollX = window.pageXOffset || body.scrollLeft;
  var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || body.scrollTop;
  _x = rawDom.getBoundingClientRect().left + scrollX;
  _y = rawDom.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollY;
  return { left: _x, top: _y };
}
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.