# Angularjs - unable to show/hide element according to scroll location

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I'm trying to show an arrow icon to be used as "go to top" button, but only after some scrolling done by the user. The code used to work great using `jquery`, but I'm having hard time to achieve the same effect using `angular`. At the moment, the arrow is always seen in the bottom right corner of the screen.

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8hn5cws7/).

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     //detect scroll
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(scroll);
        if(scroll>500 || scroll==undefined){
            $scope.showUpArrow = false;
        }else{
            $scope.showUpArrow = true;
        }
    });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-hide="showUpArrow" id="goUp-cont">
      <a href="#top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-4x" id="goUp"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See this answer... do it the angular way if you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319551/angularjs-scrolltop-equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gonna need to manually $apply() (or $digest()) your scope, as you are in a jquery handler, so basically outside of angular cycle.

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     //detect scroll
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(scroll);
        if(scroll>500 || scroll==undefined){
            $scope.showUpArrow = false;
        }else{
            $scope.showUpArrow = true;
        }
        **$scope.$apply();**
    });
}]);
```

should basically fix your problem

To avoid expensive digestion cycles on each scroll event when they are, most of the time, useless, you should also check the initial value of showUpArrow, triggering the digest cycle only if the value changed :

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     //detect scroll
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var oldState = $scope.showUpArrow;
        console.log(scroll);
        if(scroll>500 || scroll==undefined){
            $scope.showUpArrow = false;
        }else{
            $scope.showUpArrow = true;
        }
        if($scope.showUpArrow !== oldState) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Only one thing, the arrow is seen when the page first loads, why is so? `showUpArrow` is first evaluated to `false`.

Comment: @undroid, it is first evaluated to `false` because you have `ng-hide="showUpArrow"` in your HTML. It should be `ng-show="showUpArrow"`, i updated [a fiddle with those modifications](http://jsfiddle.net/8hn5cws7/4/)

Answer (score 2):

A call `$scope.apply()` is missing:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    if(scroll>500 || scroll==undefined){
        $scope.showUpArrow = false;
    }else{
        $scope.showUpArrow = true;
    }
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

See it working on [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hn5cws7/1/)

More info on why you have to do this: [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) for example