# How to implement ng-show based on position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and seem to be having issues figuring out how to customize ng-show/ng-hide. I would like for the below pasted nav bar to appear once the user has scrolled 600px down the page. Because I can't use jQuery with angular, I am a bit confused how to add this functionality.

I currently am connecting this to an auth controller that has a lot of irrelevant code, which I haven't posted it.

```
    <nav ng-hide="true" class='homeNoAuth'>
        <span class='nav navbar-fixed-top'>
            <h1 id='homeLogo' ui-sref='home'>Title</h1>
            <span class='navElement' ui-sref='signin'>Log In</span>
            <span class='navElement' ui-sref='signup'>Sign Up</span>
            <span class='navElement' ui-sref='about'>About</span>

            <span class="search input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </nav>
```

Any advice would be amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the effect you are looking for with a simple directive watching the $window object scroll event. By tracking the offset, you can show or hide content based on the scroll position.

```
<body scroll id="page">
    <header></header>
    <nav ng-hide="!showContent" class='homeNoAuth'>
        <span class='nav navbar-fixed-top'>
            <h1 id='homeLogo' ui-sref='home'>Title</h1>
            <span class='navElement' ui-sref='signin'>Log In</span>
            <span class='navElement' ui-sref='signup'>Sign Up</span>
            <span class='navElement' ui-sref='about'>About</span>

            <span class="search input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </nav>
    <section></section>

</body>


.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= 600) {
                 scope.showContent = true;
             } else {
                 scope.showContent = false;
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
})
```

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/AwQfpmHOJDOd6Uc7tjGy?p=preview

EDIT:

```
// Cleaner version of same directive
.directive("scroll", ["$window", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            scope.$apply(scope.showContent = this.pageYOffset >= 600 ? true : false);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Yay! This response was amazing. So easy and elegant and loved that it forced me to use a custom directive, which I need to not be scared of. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To make the directive a little cleaner, the if/else can be replaced with a ternary... scope.showContent = this.pageYOffset >= 600 ? true : false;

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this would be to add a directive to your app. I've put together a directive that should work inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549510/2528925) (no testing).

```
app.directive('ngShowAfterScroll', function($window) {
  return {
    scope: {
      showOnScroll: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var $w = angular.element($window);
      var visible = false;
      element.addClass('ng-hide')
      var doc = document.documentElement;
      var handler = function() {
        var top = ($w.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
        if(!visible && top >= scope.showOnScroll) {
          visible = true;
          element.removeClass('ng-hide');
        }
        else if(visible && top < scope.showOnScroll) {
          visible = false;
          element.addClass('ng-hide');
        }
      }
      $w.on('scroll', handler);
      handler();
    }
  };
});
```

Use it in your html like this:

```
<div ng-show-after-scroll="600"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like it would work to me, but there might be some issues with it interacting with my other code bc it isn't showing up at all. This bar was part of a multi view page with one of the pages having infinite scroll. I really appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: If you're not scrolling the whole document, you'll want to change `var top` to equal your scrolling container's scrolltop and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the $window object to your controller and then use it with your scope giving you access to $window.scrollY . Is not the cleanest approach but it works.

```
 controller('ctrl', function($scope,$window ){

 $scope.$watch(function(){});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I used one of the custom directives, but this is a great little trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `$window` into your controller, and listen for the `'scroll'` event.

```
app.controller('RootController', [ '$scope', '$window', '$document',
    function ($scope, $window, $document) {
        var wnd = $window,
            doc = $document[0];

        $scope.showNav = true;
        wnd.onscroll = function () {
            var scrollY = wnd.pageYOffset
                || doc.documentElement.scrollTop
                || doc.body.scrollTop;
            $scope.showNav = scrollY >= 600;
        };
    }
]);
```

Then, in your templates,

```
<nav ng-show="showNav" class="homeNoAuth">...</nav>
```

Comment: This is the response I initially used and tweaked but it became buggy with a multi view page with one of the pages having infinite scroll. After a little bit in the infinite scroll, it would disappear. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond! It really did help me further explore angular.